# How to instantiate objects dynamically in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to know if there is a way to create any number of instances of an object dynamically in C# using a for loop.

Please provide a sample of code. Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm assuming you mean something other than `for(int i=0; i<10; i++){ var o = new Foo(); }`

Comment: yes I need informationo about Dynamic objects

Comment: Here is a linko about Dynamic objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep references to your objects with a list:

```
        var myobjects = new List<System.Security.Cryptography.MD5>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            myobjects.Add(System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create());
        }
```

and iterate through the list:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            myobjects[i].ComputeHash(new byte[] { (byte)i });
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString( myobjects[i].Hash));
        }
```

Otherwise Reusing the same variable will make the previous object go out of scope, and dispose itself.